# Create bar with repeating image in Sprite Kit scene - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am working on an iOS game with the Sprite Kit template from Xcode.

In my actual gameplay scene I need to add a top bar which should use a pattern that will repeat on x-axis until the end of screen.

I've tried this:

```
topBar = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] init];
topBar.color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topBar"]];
topBar.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame));
[self addChild:topBar];
```

This doesn't work unless I provide a color to UIColor, not an image. I read on this forum that apparently SKSpriteNode doesn't support colorWithPatternImage.

So my next try was to add an UIView and use colorWithPatternImage on the background of the view. However this returns nothing, not even whiteColor when I use color not image:

```
topBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame), self.frame.size.width, 40)];
topBar.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

[self.view addSubview:topBar];
```

Any idea what the correct approach would be for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SKSpriteNode does not support UIColor with or generated from a pattern, only solid colors can be applied.

Instead use a pattern image to create a sprite with the desired pattern. If you make the pattern image grayscale you can use SKSpriteNode's `color` and `colorBlendFactor` properties to change the color of the pattern image/sprite to any color and any color brightness you need.

Comment: I understand that SKSpriteNode cannot support it. You are suggesting to create 1 sprite node with the image i want to repeat?.. In this case, since my image is 2px wide, how do I make it fill the screen in width? I also thought about creating sprite nodes with the image using a 'for' loop, but wouldn't that cause problems regarding the efficiency?

Comment: You can make the pattern image larger, or repeat it by creating multiple sprites. Probably both to balance number of sprites vs size of texture but if in doubt just use a full-size image because it'll be easiest to work with that.

Comment: OMG. I can't believe it was so easy :) I thought that if my image is 2px and I assign a much larger width to it it would look like poor quality, as it happens when creating websites. Apparently it's not the case. The code that fixed it: `topBar = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"topBar"];
        topBar.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 80);
        
        topBar.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame));
        [self addChild:topBar];
`  Thank you for the help.